# Generating Dynamic SSML from "HTTP Request" to be used on a "Get Input"

Tags: plivo, ssml, amazon-polly

I'm wondering if anyone can be of assistance.

I am trying to generate some dynamic Amazon Polly SSML to be used on the Plivo PHLO platform. When someone dials into a particular number, they should be greeted with a custom message (in a particular language) and prompted to enter a number.

I have an **HTTP request** that hits my API, which receives the request and generates the SSML using Plivo's PHP Server SDK.

```
$response = new Response();
$speak_elem = $response->addSpeak($result['text'], ['language'=> 'en-US, 'voice'=>"Polly.Joanna"]);

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
die( $response->toXML() );
```

It seems to me that this **HTTP Request** is working perfectly and returning perfect SSML. When I copy and hard-code-paste the SSML into the **Get Input** node, it works OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response><Speak language="en-US" voice="Polly.Joanna">Welcome To 101 Broadway. For English, press 1.</Speak></Response>
```

However, when I try to add a **Get Input** component and link it's "prompt" audio to the resulting SSML, I am getting an error that says **Invalid SSML** (See Screenshots at the bottom).

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- I've tried returning the SSML in plain XML and using `{{HTTP_Welcome.response}}`
- I've tried returning the SSML as text in a JSON object called SSML and using `{{HTTP_Welcome.response.SSML}}`
- I've tried returning the SSML both with and without the ***xml*** tag.
- I've tried returning the SSML both with and without the ***Result*** tag.
- I've tried taking a break and coming back to it. Hey, you never know.

No matter how I return the SSML, and how I try to link it to the **Get Input** prompt, I am unsuccessful. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible?

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks!

***SCREENSHOT 1***

[image: Validated SSML]

***SCREENSHOT 2***

[image: PHLO Error]

Comment: According to Plivo Support, the functionality is not available. They are looking into implementing this, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

My name is Mohammed Huzaif, and I work for Plivo as a Developer Evangelist.

Unfortunately, the "GetInput node" in PHLO does not yet implement the feature you are searching for. The best option is to use a standard speak which is customisable in your way, which may have a less natural feel than SSML.

Currently, I've narrow information about your use case as of now but If you still want to use a custom SSML, I'd recommend utilising a framework instead of PHLO to design your call flow. Here's a tutorial that covers a few [use cases](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/make-outbound-calls/python/) by Plivo in several frameworks to help you develop one.

If you experience any problems, please feel free to contact our [support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us).